# XAML background color and text color not changing

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I do not know if my code displays a list of `FOOS` .It does generate a list item that is clickable which goes to the correct Details page, the problem is the list item is either blank or all the text is white. I cannot figure out which.[image]

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MaopApplication.Views.PipelineSearch">
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"  >
            <Entry Placeholder="Search With PipelineName" Text="{Binding SearchText}"  ></Entry>
            <Button Text="Search" Command="{Binding SearchPipes}"    />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Foos}"  ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped" ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View BackgroundColor="Red">
                            <StackLayout>
                                <label Text="wtf" TextColor="Black"></label>
                                <label Text="{Binding Test}"TextColor="Black"/>
                             </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

***CODE TO CREATE FOOS***

`var Foos = new List<object>() {new {Test = "foo"}, new {Test = "bar"}};`

Comment: Weird. Do you see any error messages in the Output window? Could you post the code you are using to fill in `Foos`?

Comment: No Errors. at all

Comment: Can you try for listview:  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"

Comment: Random things to try when debuggin Xamarin Forms... Restart device/simulator, reset device/simulator, restart Visual Studio, restart computer......  I often run into issues where Xaml changes aren't picked up in incremental builds and either have delete the app form the device and do a clean on the solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple things wrong here (maybe it was just a bad copy/paste job):

- `ViewCell.View` does not have a `BackgroundColor` property, use `StackLayout.BackgroundColor` instead
- `label` should be `Label` (capitals matter)

When I made those change to your code, it ran fine for me:

```
<ViewCell>
  <ViewCell.View>
    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red">
      <Label Text="wtf" TextColor="Black"/>
      <label Text="{Binding Test}" TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </ViewCell.View>
</ViewCell>
```

Comment: Thank you very much